# DataGrip view JSON in pretty

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip, intellij-datagrip

Is there a way to view JSON in a pretty format with lines wrapped when selecting the column in DataGrip? In MySQL Workbench there's a nice option of "Open value in Editor". The "Edit Maximized" does not wrap or fit in screen.

DataGrip:
[image]

MySQL Workbench
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the moment you need to invoke `Reformat code` action when you're inside a cell.

Before:
[image: before]

After reformat:
[image: after]

Follow the issue [DBE-6670](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6670)

Update:
[Starting from 2020.3](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6670/Implement-ViewEdit-Maximized-reformatted-action-for-grid-editor-cell#focus=Comments-27-4483956.0-0) **Toggle Formatting** button in cells Value Editor (right-click on cell, choose **Maximize**)
The formatting mode is available for one-line JSON and XML values. It's turned on by default.

Comment: Thanks, at least I can see it pretty though had to undo the formatting changes. It's good that Jetbrains is actively pursuing the issue now.

Comment: Yes, we (DataGrip) hope to have the pretty viewer in 2020.2

Answer (score 15):

You can use the **Value Editor** function which is available in the output panel of DataGrip.

[image]

When it's opened and you click on a cell in JSON format, the JSON will be shown prettified in the box.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

DataGrip 2022.2.2 here.

Staying in the cell of type "text" and formatting by CTRL+ALT+L didn't work for me. A message saying that the content is already formatted popped up.
This only worked when I change the column type to "json".

What has worked for a regular text column is opening the Value Editor by Shift+Enter, then inside the editor right-clicking on an empty space and setting JSON as the formatting language by choosing "Set Highlighting Language..." in the popped-up menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively and if you use PostgreSQL, you can do pretty-format right in the query. Assume `items` column is a `jsonb` column:

```sql
select id, active, jsonb_pretty(items::jsonb) from orders;
```